# What does this firebase error mean and how can I fix it?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I am running into an issue where a call to write a value in my database gets permission denied. So I went into the console to simulate the request to see which rule it is failing and when I run the simulation I get an error message that looks like this:

```
Error running simulation — Failed to parse payload <Entire rules text here>...(5223)...
```

My rules are much longer than the error could print so it actually only print's part of it, but it is implied to be that the whole rule set would get printed if there was room for it. Also, despite the error, the rules were able to be deployed via the console with no issues. It might also be worth noting that I am using bolt to compile my rules, but I have also inspected the generated rule for this particular request and it looks ok to me.

I'm not really sure how to even start troubleshooting this other than blindly start reducing my rule set until it starts working. So any suggestions for what to try would be great, or if someone has encountered this error before and knows what is causing it that would be even better!